# In Orbeon Forms, how can I change the luanguage of Date Field Input?

Tags: forms, date, calendar, orbeon, lang

How to change the language of the calendar field in (form-runner) to the language 'fr'. I try to insert properties below into properties-local.xml. Despite that, the field of the date shows days in English language.

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.default-language.*.* "value="fr" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.default-language" value="fr" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.available-languages"
value="fr" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.available-languages.orbeon.builder" value="fr" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.default-language.orbeon.builder"
value="fr" />
```

Besides that, I tried to modify in resources.xml to keep the language 'fr' and delete others languages but i haven't a result for that.

Thanks in advance.

@Evernet: this is a screenshot of selected luangages in my Form Builder
[image]

Comment: Hi Lebki. Is this for a form you created with Form Builder? If so, it is in Form Builder that you should set the language for the form to be in French. You can add French using the "+" to the right of "English" at the top-right of the screen, and then you can remove English. With this, the datepicker should show in French. You'll let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Evernet, i added a screenshot in my post to show that the language selected by default is French(Français) but when i open the Form from my application(mode embedding) the datepicker showed in english.

Comment: And your form is only available in French? (Not in French and English?) Can you reproduce this problem on http://demo.orbeon.com/? What version of Orbeon Forms are you on?

Comment: Yes my Form was only available in French , the version of Orbeon Form was 2016.2.201608230022-PE .When i try to reproduce this in demo.orbeon.com the datepicker was correct also when i tried in my Form builder, the datepicker was in French.The problem was reproduced when i open the Form from my application(Java) in embedding mode.

Comment: Got it, so this is with 2016.2, and only happens when loading the form through the Java embedding API. @ebruchez will have a look at this and follow-up with you on this.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So i'm waiting his return.

Comment: Lebki, sorry about the delay on this. Is this still a current issue?